# Playing sound in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an application in which there is a timer, after which a signal should sound. I write on xamarin.forms (c#), currently for android, but the application will be on iPhone in the future. The sound file itself is located in res/raw/audio.mp3 and assets/audio.mp3 (I did not understand exactly where the file should be located, they write one somewhere, somewhere else).

When using MediaPlayer, it is not possible to play the sound, because an error crashes, allegedly the file was not found:

```
var player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource("android.resource://com.example.timer/raw/audio.mp3"); //error, file not found
player.Prepare();
```

I specified the file in different ways, starting from the full path and ending only with the name - the result is the same, the file was not found.

Then it turned out that it was necessary to use `DependencyService` as indicated [here](https://wcoder.github.io/notes/playing-audio-mp3-file-in-xamarin-forms).
But it also did not lead to a positive result - an error is still observed.

Comment: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager

Answer (score 0):

In xamarin form, you can use [Xamarin Community Toolkit MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement) to achieve this.

`MediaElement` is a view for playing video and audio. Media that's supported by the underlying platform can be played from the following sources:

- The web, using a URI (HTTP or HTTPS).
- A resource embedded in the platform application, using the
  `ms-appx:///` URI scheme.
- Files that come from the app's local and temporary data folders,
  using the `ms-appdata:///` URI scheme.
- The device's library.

You can also check the official sample here: [MediaElement Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-mediaelementdemos/).

**Note:**

If you want to play media from the local folder of your app, you can check : [Play media from the app's local and temporary folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/mediaelement#play-media-from-the-apps-local-and-temporary-folders).

A `MediaElement` can play media files that are copied into the app's local or temporary data folders, using the `ms-appdata:///` URI scheme.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<MediaElement Source="ms-appdata:///local/XamarinVideo.mp4"
              ShowsPlaybackControls="True" />
```